# Need help leaving a cell blank if the formula has no sum value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using the below formula to calculate attendance and I would like the summary column to remain blank if there is no value entered from columns `B12:AF12`.

What am I missing to make this happen?

I tried putting `""` on the outside of the last bracket and then closing everything but this is not working.

Below is my formula that I am using to sum up my row:

```
=COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S")+(COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S/")/2)
```

Comment: Wrap your formula in an `IF` statement checking if there are values in the range being checke: `IF(COUNTA(B12:AF12)=0,"",COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S")+(COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S/")/2)))`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, that looks like more of an answer, so it should be in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Thank you this worked.

Comment: `=IFERROR(1/1/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B12:AF12,{"S","S","S/"})/2),"")`

Answer (score 0):

You would want to nest your COUNTIFS inside an IF statement, something like this could work:

IF(COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S")+COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S/")=0,"",COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S")+COUNTIF(B12:AF12,"S/")/2)

When the IF statement evaluates to TRUE, the output is "" (blank), else the output is the formula you have specified.

Comment: The SUM will always return `0` as the cells are filled with text strings and sum will ignore them.

Comment: @ScottCraner - nothing in the OP clearly indicates that the cells are filled with text strings - where are you getting that information?

Comment: The fact that they are trying to count `S` and `S/` which are text strings.  SUM will ignore them and return `0`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that keeps the repitition down:

```
=IFERROR(1/1/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B12:AF12,{"S","S","S/"})/2),"")
```

It does 3 countifs dividing the output by 2, but since `S` is counted twice it returns the actual count.

If the output of the sumproduct is 0 then we get an error as we try to divide by `0` and the IFERROR will output the `""`